# Check constraint not reading [A-Z]?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I am having an issue with a check constraint reading [A-Z].

here is the code:

```
drop table test CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

Create table test (
post Varchar2(6),
CHECK (post like '[A-Z]')
);

insert into test values ('A');
```

And I receive a "check constraint violated" error after trying to insert A. Any feedback would be appreciated. Even if it does work for you because everything is telling me it should work.

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: Oracle version 18.4.0.0.0 @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: The way you put it, only `insert into test values ('[A-Z]')` would work. It is **regexp_like** you're looking for (see Tim's answer).

Comment: LIKE doesn't support regular expressions in SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
    post Varchar2(6),
    CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(post, '^[A-Z]+$'))
);
```

The pattern `^[A-Z]+$` would match posts which only contain capital letters.  If instead you want to flag posts which begin with a capital letter, then use `^[A-Z]`.